# How can I cleanly build one project in git that relies on artifacts from another project

Tags: git, teamcity

If I have two projects, one that outputs a .dll and .lib stub, and another that links to the .lib stub, and by extension uses the generated .dll at runtime, how can I set up my TC build system and GIT repository to cleanly:

1. allow a user to checkout the client application, build it, and run it without having to go find the latest .dll/.lib files
2. keep official builds and TC builds of the client application in sync; if I checkout and run locally, it behaves the same as it does with the TC build version, using the same .dll and .lib

My initial thoughts are to either have the appropriate .lib and .dll files in the client application (like 3rd party binaries), which are then checked in by TC whenever a new .dll is built; it's a little strange to have TC *pushing* into git, but it seems it might work. Or, I could have the logic in a pre-build step of the solution that goes out to TC to get the latest binaries, which I like less because the building user may not have credentials for TC, and they may not actually want to get the latest versions.

If the first solution is the way to go, is there easy support in TC for this? Or would I have to do a full checkout, update, add/commit, push during the build process? Are there any pitfalls with these solutions that I haven't considered?

Comment: Have you looked at submodules

Comment: Output the dll and lib as an artifact from the first build and depend on it in the second.

Comment: @JamesWoolfenden That was my first thought, but it doesn't satisfy either #1 or #2 of the above

Comment: Teamcity stores artifacts in the built in ivy and nuget caches. Use those in the cmdline version, depending on your platform.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a script which will download libraries on developer machine from TeamCity build configuration. This script will be used locally. See also http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Patterns+For+Accessing+Build+Artifacts

On the server you can use snapshot+artifact dependencies to keep building of these projects in sync: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Build+Dependencies+Setup

Snapshot dependency provides sources synchronization, so if you change some API in library and it's usage in dependent project at the same time, you can be sure TeamCity will build it correctly.

Comment: Definitely a viable solution (very similar to the 2nd one I suggested); my only gripe is that this script either *always* runs on dev machines, or there is an extra step that developers have to manually perform in certain circumstances.

Comment: Yes, if this is a big problem in your environment, then you can place dlls in git submodule, as suggested above. But someone will have to move sobmodule forward every time when dll is updated.